# Validation using regular expression

Tags: regex

The field name can have a maximum of 15 characters and only alphanumeric characters and hyphens are allowed. Using only numeric values in the field is not allowed.
How can I write a regular expression all above Should work. 
, Is it possible in a if else ladder. without regular expression how can I achieve this validation?

Comment: How? You can start by [reading a reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) and [testing them](http://regexpal.com/)

Comment: For alphanumaric and hypan i using  var alphanum = /^[a-zA-Z0-9-]+$/;

Comment: if you are using asp .net consider property validation inside viewmodel.

Comment: Tag Your Question Properly and show your effort what you try?

Comment: See all Eric got what i mean....Thanks Eric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This expression should match 1 to 15 alphanumeric characters and not match only numeric values.

```
^(?=.*[a-zA-Z\-])[a-zA-Z0-9\-]{1,15}$
```

You can learn more about "advanced" regular expressions in the link below.

http://www.regular-expressions.info/refadv.html

Comment: yes tou are true if i enter a value john1234 it shoul accept.

Comment: Wowwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww this what am asking...your graet..thanks baba

Answer (score 0):

The following reg exp will allow only hypen and alphabet char.. if you want more just modify it....

```
var reg = /^(?:[a-zA-Z]+-?)+$/ ;

$('#first_name').blur(function(){
    if(!$('#first_name').val())
        alert("please fill your firstname");
    else if(!reg.test($('#first_name').val()))
        alert('Only alphabets & hypen space allowed!');     
    else if($('#first_name').val().length > 15)
        alert('Enter your name between 15 characters ');    

});
```

I have given example using jquery validations...
You sholud also try in your own way for getting your requirement ...

Comment: this is nice idea but i need not alphabet, i need alphanumaric charcter

Comment: this will work..var reg = /^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+-?)+$/ ; and you should also try ssome thing as you wont always get a piece of cake...

Comment: Yes i try this, and make it fixed

Comment: yes i accepted, i dont know why people is votdown my doubt, if they think high no need of a stck overflow account to anyone. Thanks pushparaj

Comment: not like that ..you should give more details as what you want.. what you tried and what output you got and what actual output you need...